# Servlet URl mapping

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet wich generates a picture, "pictureServlet" to reach the servlet i use :

```
URL pictureURL = new URL("http://localhost:8888/Picture-portlet/pictureServlet");
Embedded Picture = new Embedded("", new ExternalResource(pictureURL));
window.addComponent(Picture);
```

the Code is being executed in a Portlet(Vaadin) if i click on a button the picture is being added to the portlet.

the problem is that i can only reach the servlet as long as i use it on localhost , e.g if i want to reach the servlet from another host : http://mypage.de:8888how do i tell my servlet that he should use the host http://mypage.de:8888 and not the localhost , http://localhost:8888

Comment: What servlet engine are you using? Tomcat? Jetty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one you are using different ports. As it looks, your server is listening on port 8888 so http://mypage.de:8888 should work just as well as http://localhost:8888. http://mypage.de:8080 will, however, not work unless you have configured a listener on port 8080. To do that, edit your server.xml (in the tomcat conf directory) and add a connector for port 8080 inside the `<Service>` section

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *how do i tell my servlet that he should use the host http://mypage.de:8888 and not the localhost , http://localhost:8888*

Just change the URL accordingly.

```
URL pictureURL = new URL("http://mypage.de:8888/Picture-portlet/pictureServlet");
// ...
```